# How do I using Generic as parameter and return specific object without casting?

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

Does function can return specific object, when I input a specific class.
My problem:
I don't know how to return a object. take a look following code and thanks

class MyViewControler {
    }

```
class MySplitViewController: NSSplitViewControler {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        /* 
         * get specific object 
         */
        let vc = viewController(for: MyViewControler.self)
    }
}

extension NSSplitViewController {

    public func viewController<T>(for anClass: T) -> T.object {

        guard let tClass = anClass as? AnyClass else { return nil }
        var vc: NSViewController?
        if let idx = self.splitViewItems.index(where: { $0.viewController.classForCoder == tClass} ) {
            vc = self.splitViewItems[idx].viewController
        }
    }
    /*
     * I don't know how to return a specific object 
     */
    return vc
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of a method taking a type and returning an
(optional) instance of that type would be:

```
public func viewController<T>(for aClass: T.Type) -> T?
```

or, if you want to restrict it to subclasses of `NSViewController`:

```
public func viewController<T: NSViewController>(for aClass: T.Type) -> T?
```

The implementation can be simplified with optional binding:

```
extension NSSplitViewController {
    public func viewController<T: NSViewController>(for aClass: T.Type) -> T? {
        for item in self.splitViewItems {
            if let vc = item.viewController as? T {
                return vc
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Or as a "one-liner":

```
extension NSSplitViewController {
    public func viewController<T: NSViewController>(for aClass: T.Type) -> T? {
        return self.splitViewItems.lazy.flatMap { $0.viewController as? T }.first
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin R. Thanks for help

Comment: Will the `.lazy` in combination with `.first` here mean we only apply the `flatMap` on elements until a successful conversion of `T`?

Comment: @dfri: Exactly. Without `lazy`, `flatMap` returns an array with all mapped elements, and then the first element is taken. Here, `flatMap` returns a `Lazy<Something>Collection` which is evaluated lazily. – In this particular application  the difference wouldn't be noticeable, but it does exactly what the above explicit loop does.